# How to automatically populate fields in FormFlow based on previous input

Tags: c#, botframework, formflow

I'm using FormFlow and would like to automatically populate some of the next fields based on the answers.

For instance in the following code, if a user answers the question of CloudType with NationalCloud I would like to automatically set the value of ClusterPurpose to 1 and not to ask for it's value. In case a user answer CloudType with PublicCloud I would like to ask for the ClusterPurpose.

What is the best way to achieve this?

```
public static IForm<MyForm> BuildForm()
        {
            var customFormBuilder = CreateCustomFormBuilder<MyForm>();
            return customFormBuilder
                .Field(nameof(CloudType))
                .Field(nameof(NationalCloudType), active: state => !IsPublicCloudChosen(state))
                .Field(nameof(ClusterPurpose))
                .CompleteRequestForm();
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set state.ClusterPurpose when validating CloudType input and hide  ClusterPurpose field if state.CloudType is NationalCloud.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's indeed an option, I was looking for a more code clean way. It seems like magic that values are populated in the validate of another field. If I don't find anything better I will mark that as the answer.